# Error when clicking image: Unexpected Token }

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image which is supposed to run a function when clicking it, but for a strange reason I am getting the error "Unexpected Token }". Here is my code:
HTML:

```
  <img src='images/buildings/house_3.png' onClick='selectbuilding('house');'>
```

Javascript:

```
function selectbuilding(whichbuilding)
{
    building = whichbuilding;
    buildingselected = 1;
    if (building == "house") {
        document.getElementById('maparea').innerHTML="<form method='post'><h2>Base</h2><input id='button' type='button' name='button' onclick='myFunction();' value='Close'/><input id='button' type='button' name='button' onclick='checkelement();' value='Upgrade Base'/></form>";
    }
    if (building == "wood") {
        document.getElementById('maparea').innerHTML="<form method='post'><h2>Wood</h2><input id='button' type='button' name='button' onclick='myFunction();' value='Close'/><input id='button' type='button' name='button' onclick='checkelement();' value='Upgrade Wood'/></form>";
    }
    else {
document.getElementById('selectbuilding').innerHTML="<img src='images/buildings/" + building + "_3.png'>";
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Try changing this onClick='selectbuilding('house');' to onClick="selectbuilding('house')"

Comment: You cannot place single quotes inside single quotes without escaping them or using double quotes. The code coloring in the question makes is pretty obvious it's not picking it up as a string.

Comment: Thanks but there is a problem. I am using this code to create that image: theDiv.innerHTML += "<img src='images/buildings/house_3.png' onClick='selectbuilding('house');'>"; If I change that I get a syntax error.

Comment: @geotsak *"You cannot place single quotes inside single quotes without escaping them ..."*

Comment: "<img src='images/buildings/house_3.png' onClick='selectbuilding(\'house \');'>";

Comment: @GeorgettePincin: That's equivalent to not escaping the single quotes.  `"foo'bar"` and `"foo\'bar"` produce the same string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the HTML, especially the attribute value. How should the parser know that the attribute value ends at the fourth `'`, not the second? It can't.

The code you wrote is equivalent to

```
<img onClick='selectbuilding(' />
```

which internally creates something like

```
function handler(event) {
    selectbuilding(
}
```

which is clearly not valid JavaScript. Use double quotes for the function argument or the attribute value.

Comment: Thanks but there is a problem. I am using this code to create that image:        theDiv.innerHTML += "<img src='images/buildings/house_3.png' onClick='selectbuilding('house');'>"; If I change that I get a syntax error.

Comment: @geotsak Escape the single quotes `\'`.

Comment: @geotsak: If you want to put a literal double quote inside a double quoted string literal you need to escape it: `"foo(\"bar\")"`.

Comment: @Spencer: That won't help. `"foo'bar"` and `"foo\'bar"` produce the same string value.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: But this is part of a string literal delimited with double quotes: `innerHTML += "... 'selectbuilding('house');' ... ";` The single quotes are just normal characters, they don't need to and cannot be escaped. You can see here that it doesn't make a difference: http://jsfiddle.net/arxzbwy6/